# Avoiding words of node memory still in use

Tags: memory

I am using `lualatex` on a file `wasp.ltx` and getting

```
 427 words of node memory still in use:
   4 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 4 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 7 attribute, 46 glue_spec
, 5 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
```

What is happening here and how can I avoid this `node memory still in use`?

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{letter}

\title{First document}
\author{Randy}
\date{September 2022}

\signature{Randy}

\address{300 North Broadway \\
Lexington, KY 40508 USA}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Mayor, Deputy Mayor, and Councillors; Zabbar}

  \opening{Dear Members of the Zabbar Local Council}

  Body

  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}
  \signature{Randy}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. It's difficult to debug code that you don't show... Please reduce your code as much as possible while still triggering the problem, and post it here.

Comment: I believe it's a perfectly normal message. I get it with `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}test\end{document}`

Comment: Thought it has been saving some information from previously creating files.